# OpenCensus metrics and stats handling coordinated omission

Tags: performance-testing, metrics, micrometer

I was looking for information around how OpenCensus metrics handles the problem of "coordinated omission".

As far as I saw Micrometer from http://micrometer.io uses the **LatencyUtils** http://latencyutils.github.io/LatencyUtils/ by Gil Tene to solve this issue, but I couldn't find anything like that for OpenCensus.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be helpful.

Comment: Reading about this problem right now. Can you tell me where do you want to use opencensus and why this problem is relevant for your use-case?

Comment: @BogdanDrutu apparently OpenCensus already handles this. I have found a reference to Gil Tene talk "How NOT to Measure Latency" on this OpenCensus page https://opencensus.io/stats/sampling/.